# passing dictionary as parameter for mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I had semi working, unsafe set of functions for mysql.connector that can accept data in a form like one below. It is flexible as I could design any size of dictionary i need.

```
db_data={
"column01" : 'test',
"column02" : 51,
"column03" : None
}
columns = db_data.keys()
values = db_data.values()
tablename = "mytable"
```

It "works" fine but it is unsafe (although it is only for internal use so I did not care about safety here) but I am also not able to pass "None" (Null object) to mysql.

```
unsafe_query = "INSERT INTO {0:s} ({1:s}) VALUES ({2:s})".format(tablename, ', '.join(map(str, columns)), ','.join(map(repr, values)))
cursor.execute(unsafe_query)
```

I will get an error:

```
Something went wrong: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'
```

Following suggestion of how it should be properly designed, I've tried this way but I cannot get string formatting to pass dictionary same way anymore and I'm little stuck here:

```
safe_query = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.execute(safe_query, (tablename, ', '.join(map(repr, columns)), ', '.join(map(repr, values))) )
# cursor.execute(safe_query, (tablename, ', '.join(map(str, columns)), ', '.join(map(str, values))) ) # this won't work either
```

Getting error:

```
Something went wrong: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''mytable' ('\'column01\', \'column02\', \'column03\'') VALUES ('\'test\', ' at line 1
```

Maybe someone could suggest how to get around it and get mysql Null object to work. Ideally would be to have a proper, safe query but that's not the most important issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want your values to be handled by the driver and averything else composed as a string:

```py
query = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})".format(tablename, ', '.join(columns), ','.join(['%s']*len(values)))
cursor.execute(query, values)
```

Even better, you could use the dict directly:

```py
query = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})".format(tablename, ', '.join(columns), ','.join(['%({})s'.format(colname) for colname in columns]))
cursor.execute(query, db_data)
```

Anyway, I would not encourage such string formatting in the first place. If you now the tablename and columnnames beforehand and that's not going to change, you'll probably have a more readable and reliable code by hardcoding everything but the values.

Comment: thanks josoler! Second suggestion worked but first is errors with `right syntax to use near '%s,%s,%s). Maybe because 'None' is not counted ??

Comment: @tmdag `None` should be counted as well. I don't know what I'm missing here, maybe your driver doesn't accept values as a list at all, and it can only accept dicts. What driver are you using?

Comment: all good, had to convert values to tuple(colvals.get("values")). Thanks!